# Delphi XE7 crashses at shutdown

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Since I installed Delphi XE7 I have this nasty crash as shutdown:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: bds.exe
  Application Version:  21.0.17707.5020
  Application Timestamp:    545bd62d
  Fault Module Name:    rtl210.bpl
  Fault Module Version: 21.0.17707.5020
  Fault Module Timestamp:   545bd940
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00016a9c
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
```

After I click the 'Close program' I get:

> Exception EAccessViolation in module rtl210.bpl at 00016A9C.
>   Access violation at address 50066A9C in module 'rtl210.bpl'. Read of
>   address 075F2AF8.

I checked the call stack but it doesn't really makes any sense.

To see the call stack I started Delphi, then in 'Load process' I entered Delphi's path ( "C:\Delphi\XE7\bin\bds.exe" ).
I cannot set the '-p delphi' parameter in 'Parameters' box because when the second Delphi process is started it will complain that it cannot access the license file (which is blocked by the first Delphi process).

Call stack:

```
:50066a9c rtl210.@System@@IntfClear$qqrr44System@%DelphiInterface$17System@IInterface% + 0x10
:08baffdd fmx210.@System@Generics@Collections@%TList__1$56System@%DelphiInterface$29Fmx@Behaviormanager@IListener%%@SetCount$qqri + 0x49
:50061099 rtl210.@System@@Halt0$qqrv + 0xb1
:77378bd4 ntdll.wcsncmp + 0x88
:77342710 ; ntdll.dll
:7737cb10 ntdll.LdrUnloadDll + 0x4a
:753b8be4 KERNELBASE.FreeLibrary + 0x82
:2063a191 coreide210.@Exptmain@TExpertLib@$bdtr$qqrv + 0xa9
:5005f10b rtl210.@System@TObject@Free$qqrv + 0xb
:5070ba40 vcl210.@Vcl@Forms@TCustomForm@$bdtr$qqrv + 0x58
:210f57c0 designide210.@Deskform@TDesktopForm@$bdtr$qqrv + 0x40
:761aee1c kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:7738399b ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xef
:7738396e ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0xc2
```

It says something about FMX but I never do FMX projects (still too unripe to be used). So I disable it.
What could cause the crash?

Comment: I've rolled back this (and several other of) your edits. Adding `[Delphi bug]` to the subject is not appropriate. If you have a Delphi bug to report, open a QC report at Embarcadero instead of defacing questions here. Thanks.

Comment: I've begun flagging your rude comments for the moderators. If you'll notice, much of the things you posted yesterday have been deleted by the moderators. Your insistence on continuing this nonsense is more inappropriate than your content was, and it needs to stop. (And here, it's not a "bug". It's a stupid error by a user of killing off a major part of the product and not thinking that it might cause problems. Sort of like throwing away your monitor and keyboard and then complaining because Microsoft made your computer unusable. The bug here is between the keyboard and the chair.

Comment: @KenWhite - Leaving aside your verve :) , should we understand that you never installed a new package or disabled an existing one?

Comment: @thelight: No, you should understand that I've never disabled an integral and major part of the IDE and then screamed about "bugs" in the product itself. I install new packages frequently, and disable existing ones frequently. I just don't blame other people for my own mistakes if I do something dumb in the process. (See my previous comment about MS making the computer unreliable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Delphi bug

> SOLUTION: Enable 'FMX Standard Components' package.

Details: I turned out that I had the 'FMX Standard Components' package disabled - Seems logical to disable such a large library since I don't use it. 
Well... Delphi don't like that! I enabled the library back and now I have no crash!

I could have delete the question since nobody answered posted any answer but I thought it will be useful to keep it. It documents a very important feature of Delphi: crash when the developer won't use FMX lib :)

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add a mention that you've disabled FMX because even though you've answered it, technically it would have never been solved by anyone else without that info.

Comment: @JerryDodge - Yes... I imagined that might be useful information. But until this point I have no clue (more exactly I forgot) that it is disabled.

Comment: Was it at all related to Delphi 7 installation, or was that just a temporal coincidence?

Comment: @TomBrunberg-Sorry. I was speaking about delphi xe7.